# Rudin Functional Analysis Chapter 6 Problem 18

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Express $\delta\in D^{'}(\mathbb R^2)$ in the form $$\delta(\phi)=\sum_{\beta}(-1)^{|\beta|}\int_{\mathbb R^2}f_\beta(x) \, (D^{\beta}\phi)(x)\ dx\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall \phi\in D(\mathbb R^2)$$ where $f_\beta$ is continuous function in $\mathbb R^2$.

by the result stated in rudin: since $\delta$ is a distribution of order $0$ hence $|\beta|\le2.$

I am not getting any idea how to do it. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the notation $f_\beta(D^{\beta}\phi)(x)$. Is $f_\beta$ applied to $D^\beta\phi$ and if so: how? Or should it be $f_\beta(D^{\beta}\phi(x))$?

Comment: @md2perpe i had editied the post. there $f_\beta$ is a continuous function which is getting multiplied by $D^\beta(\phi)$

Comment: Thus you mean $\int f(x) \, D^\beta\phi(x) \, dx$ with $\beta$ a multiindex?

Comment: Yes. you get it right now

Comment: I don't know of any totally continuous functions that work, but taking $u(x, y) = \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac12 \ln (x^2+y^2)$ we have $(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2) u = 2\pi \, \delta$ i.e.
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2} (\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2) \, \phi(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \phi(0, 0)$$

Comment: @md2perpe i did not get your function exactly! as how did you get it equal to $2\pi \delta$

Comment: I solved $\nabla \cdot \nabla u = 0$ in polar coordinates assuming symmetry to find $u = \ln r$. Then I tried to find the factor in front of $\delta$ through an integral and thought that it seemed to be $2\pi$ but then had a look in the [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Table_of_Green.27s_functions) to be certain.

Comment: @md2perpe sorry to say this but please can you right this more explicitly

Comment: In polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ one has 
$$\nabla \cdot \nabla u = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$$
Assuming rotation invariance so that $u = u(r)$ this reduces to
$$\nabla \cdot \nabla u = \frac{d^2 u}{d r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{d u}{d r} 
= \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \left( r \frac{du}{dr} \right)
$$
For $r>0$ we want this to equal $0$, which gives
$$r \frac{du}{dr} = A$$
for some constant $A$ and then
$$u = A \ln r + B$$
for some constant $B$.

Comment: How did you get $(\partial^2_x+\partial^2_y)u=2\pi\delta$

Comment: For $u = \ln r$ we have $(\partial_x^2+\partial_y^2)u = \nabla\cdot\nabla u = 0$ for $r>0$.Thus $\supp \nabla\cdot\nabla u = \{0\}$ and by a theorem we therefore have
$$\nabla\cdot\nabla u = c^0 \delta + \sum_{j=0}^{2} c^1_j \cdot \partial_j \delta + \sum_{k,l=0}^{n} c^2_{k,l} \partial_k \partial_l \delta + \cdots$$
for some constants $c^0, c^1_j, c^2_{k,l}, \ldots$
But as I wrote, I went to Wikipedia to find that $c^0 = 2\pi$ and that the others are $0$.